# How to compute center of an arbitrary shape in 3D?

Tags: c++, math, opengl, 3d, computational-geometry

I want to know the accurate method to find the center of an arbitrary shape in 3D.
In the figure, I have explained 3 cases.

1. In first case how can we compute the center of arbitrary points ? One idea is summation of all points divided by total number of points. Is it the only method and Is it accurate ?
2. 2nd is how to compute the approximate center of irregular arbitrary shape in 3D? Is this the same case of 1 ?
3. How can we compute the center line of the bended/curved tube that composed of arbitrary vertices ? For this problem we have to solve first two cases I think so ?

[image]

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by "center"?

Comment: This is math, not programming.

Comment: But I have to implement in programming and have a lots of algos in c ++.. :)

Comment: Agentlien@ center means approximate center. final goal is to compute the approximate center of curved tube.

Comment: @furqan: That doesn't answer the question. There are *many* ways to define what "center" means. Saying "approximate center" isn't enough information to know what you're asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution really depends on what you are actually looking for.

If you seek the average position of all points in a shape, then averaging them does indeed give you that. But it can be far off from the point which you'd intuitively say is "in the middle". For example, consider a box where one side has twice as many vertices as the opposite side. The average position would be on the half of that side, not in the middle of the box.

More likely, I'd say you are looking for the point defined by calculating the max and min bounds in each dimension and then averaging the two. Because you tagged this with C++, here's some example code:

```
// Define max and min
double max[DIMENSIONALITY];
double min[DIMENSIONALITY];

// Init max and min to max and min acceptable values here. (see numeric_limits)

// Find max and min bounds
for(size_t v_i = 0; v_i < num_vertices; ++v_i)
{
    for(int dim = 0; dim < DIMENSIONALITY; ++dim)
    {
        if(shape[v_i][dim] < min[dim]) min[dim] = shape[v_i][dim];
        if(shape[v_i][dim] > max[dim]) max[dim] = shape[v_i][dim];
    }
}

// Calculate middle
double middle[DIMENSIONALITY];
for(int dim = 0; dim < DIMENSIONALITY; ++dim) 
    middle[dim] = 0.5 * (max[dim] + min[dim]);
```

For either solution, the dimensionality of the problem doesn't matter.

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comment below, this may result in a middle point which lies outside of the shape itself. If you need a point which lies **inside** the shape, an alternative approach must be used. A simple solution could be to use ray-marching across each axis.

Comment: As soon as the polygon is concave, then this result may fall outside of the polygon.

Comment: Of course, I'm aware of that. But maybe I should point it out.

Comment: Ray tracing tri-line can be considered but .. imagine when you have a curved shape like this tube ? where you have more than 1 triangle in one infinite ray.. ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by DIMENSIONALITY.. ?

Comment: DIMENSIONALITY is simply supposed to be a constant, 3 if you have 3D, 2 in 2D, etc.. And about thoat tube: You can count the number of times you intersect lines/triangles as you march, to figure out if the calculated point is inside the shape or not. If it isn't, you can use the same count to figure out what range is within the most "centric" span. Take some time to think about it, there are very many options and variations.

Comment: Thanks... :) Will come back when I will have solution.